# jquery data table and sorting columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I'm using jquery data table to display large amounts of data inside grid. I implemented server side pagination but I'm struggling with sorting data server side.

Below is my datatable initialization, answer with query for sorting is not the subject here, I just need a way to pass information of which column is clicked to the controller, the one upon I will do the sorting.

```
('#myTable').dataTable({
      "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
        "info": false,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "stateSave": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "info": "Page _PAGE_ from _PAGES_",
         "infoEmpty": "No data",
         "oPaginate": {
             "sFirst": "First",
             "sPrevious": "Previous",
             "sNext": "Next",
             "sLast": "Last"
          },
          "ajax": {
              "url": "@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/MyController/GetData",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "data": function (d) {
                          .....
                        },
                    },
                    preDrawCallback: function (settings) {
                         ...
                    },
                    drawCallback: function (settings) {
                         ...
                    },                      
                    "columns": [
                          { "data": "Id" },
                          { "data": "FirstName" },
                          { "data": "LastName" },
                          { "data": "Age" }
                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [
                       {
                           targets: [0],
                           orderable: false
                       },
                       {
                           render: function (data, type, row) {
                               ...
                       }
                    ],
                    "order": [[0, "desc"]]
                });

public ActionResult GetData(){
   var sortColumn = ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the 'order' event like this:

```
$('#myTable').on( 'order.dt', function () {

    var order = table.order();
    var column_selected = order[0][0];
    var order_way= order[0][1];
    doStuff(column_selected ,order_way);

});
```

See it [in plugin reference](https://datatables.net/reference/event/order)

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `"serverSide": true,`, datatables will *by default* add information to the request which you need to use in your server-side code.  If you look in the Firebug Network panel, you will be able to see the request with the querystring parameters.  See [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for the full list of parameters.  Note that the link is to the v1.9 documentation, because that's what it looks like you're using.

So for sorting, you'd be interested in `iSortCol_0` and `sSortDir_0` which relate to the clicked column and the sort direction respectively.

In your controller method, you would access the parameters like this:

```
var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
var sortColumnDir = Request["sSortDir_0"];
```

You then need to incorporate this, and the other parameters into your query.

Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part) on using server-side datatables with MVC